# How to get current value of txqueuelen on Linux

Tags: linux, ifconfig

I know the following command can set `txqueuelen` in Linux:

```
ifconfig eth1 txqueuelen 4096
```

But how can I get current `txqueuelen` of a specific interface? I've tried `ifconfig eth1 txqueuelen`, it only returns the usage of ifconfig command.

Could anyone give me some idea? Many thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just run `ifconfig` as it is written there. For example:

```
user@host:~$ ifconfig 
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 04:00:32:00:00:01  
          inet addr:170.0.0.0  Bcast:170.0.255.255  Mask:255.255.192.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::999:zaga:fe78:7901/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:11857875616 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8490937839 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:4817771645749 (4.8 TB)  TX bytes:2541531991948 (2.5 TB)
```